# Azure Environment Variables in Python Cloud Service

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-cloud-services

I have a Python Cloud Service running on Microsoft Azure which should be using a different Storage Account (for blob storage and queues) when it's running in dev vs. staging vs. production.

I'd rather not hard-code the Storage Account credentials, but get them from the environment. Alternatively I would like an environment variable or something that indicates whether I'm in staging or production. When I try `print(os.environ)` I don't see any azure storage credentials, nor a value that indicates staging or production.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This is possible in Azure Web Apps, but I don't know about Azure cloud services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, since I've used a combination of solutions to make something that works for me.

I was able to define my settings in multiple ServiceConfiguration files, such as `ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg`, `ServiceConfiguration.Dev.cscfg`and `ServiceConfiguration.Production.cscfg`. Under `<ConfigurationSettings>`, add `<Setting name="settingname" value="settingvalue" />`, or use the interface in Visual Studio. When publishing you can then pick which configuration file to use, without having to modify any code. Added advantage is that these settings can also be modified via the Azure portal after the service has been published. See [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-multiple-services-project-configurations/) and [this post](http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/08/28/configuration-settings-in-an-azure-worker-role/).

The next challenge is to inject these variables into the Python environment. Unlike variables that are defined in `ServiceDefinition.csdef`, the configuration settings are not available to the Python environment. They are however stored in a DLL somewhere, can be accessed and injected into the Python environment using some C# method calls (I'm pretty ignorant about this whole process, I just followed [this post](http://www.dexterposh.com/2015/07/powershell-azure-custom-settings.html)) . Just add these lines to `LaunchWorker.ps1`, anywhere before `iex "py $worker_command"`:

```
# search for the Dll
$Splathashtable = @{
                    'Path' = "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\assembly\";
                    'Filter' = 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll';
                    'Include' = '*.dll'
                    }

$dllfile = Get-ChildItem @Splathashtable -Recurse  | Select-Object -Last 1 
# selecting only one object, in case of multiple results

# add the DLL to the current PowerShell session
Add-Type -Path $dllfile.FullName    

# Call the Static method on the class to retrieve the setting value
$Setting = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment]::GetConfigurationSettingValue('settingname')

# add setting to environment
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('settingname', $Setting)
```

Now you'll find the setting to be available in Python through `os.environ.get('SETTINGNAME')`

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom runtime variables in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file, then you can invoke it leveraging `os.environ.get('MY_ENV_NAME')`.

E.G.
The content of `ServiceDefinition.csdef` should be:

```
  <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      ...
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Startup>
      ...
    </Startup>
    <Runtime>
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="MY_ENV_NAME" value="my_value" />
        <Variable name="EMULATED">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
      ...
    </Runtime>
    ...
  </WorkerRole>
```

You can refer to http://blog.toddysm.com/2011/03/what-environment-variables-can-you-use-in-windows-azure.html for more detail.

Comment: Pretty useful, thanks! I see you can differentiate between startup and runtime, but can you also differentiate between staging and production? This is what I need.

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605042/azure-cloud-service-project-configuration-csdef-and-cscfg-in-multiple-enviro

Comment: Hi Gary, I have devised a way to get what I needed and posted it as a separate answer. Thanks for getting me on my way, I'd appreciate any comments!